# Monitor user activity in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, monitoring

I would like to make a program that monitors user activity. I do not need to know what the user is doing, all i need to know is that he is doing something. Moving the mouse, or typing. The program will be used to show to the company who is at the desk and who is gone from the workstation. So if there is no activity for 2 minutes, that means that the user is away from the computer.

I was thinking of using the keyboard hook and the mouse position to monitor changes every lets say 5 seconds. On every change I will reset the counter.

Is there a better way? (For example reading the screensaver countdown or something like that)

Comment: @BanForFun what is the purpose of asking `Have you tried something` and then post an answer? The OP clearly hasn't showed an attempt and by posting code doesn't really help the OP. We are not a coding service, rather help with specific problems and or issues on code that is in question; currently there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can P/Invoke the WinAPI's [**`GetLastInputInfo()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) function to be able to get the millisecond count at which point the last input was received *since the computer was started*.

Subtracting [**`Environment.TickCount`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) with the above will give you how many milliseconds have *lapsed* since the last input was received:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure LASTINPUTINFO
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public cbSize As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public dwTime As Integer
End Structure

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim LastInput As New LASTINPUTINFO With {.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(LASTINPUTINFO))} 'The "cbSize" field must be set every time we call the function.
    If GetLastInputInfo(LastInput) = True AndAlso _
        (Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime) >= 120000 Then '120000 ms = 120 s = 2 min.

        Timer1.Stop()
        'Computer has been idle for 2 minutes. Do your stuff here.
    End If
End Sub
```

This will check for both mouse and keyboard input.

The Timer's `Interval` property is set to `5000` to make it check every 5 seconds, and the `Enabled` property is set to `True`.

***Keep in mind*** that you must restart the timer after the two minutes of idle time have lapsed if you want it to check again.